# How to speed up parsing Neo4j ExecutionResult set?

Tags: neo4j

I am running a two part Neo4j search which is performing well. However, the actual parsing of the ExecutionResult set is taking longer than the Cypher query by a factor of 8 or 10. I'm looping through the ExecutionResult map as follows:

```
result = engine.execute("START facility=node({id}), service=node({serviceIds}) WHERE    facility-->service RETURN facility.name as facilityName, service.name as serviceName", cypherParams);

for ( Map<String, Object> row : result )
{           
    sb.append((String) row.get("facilityName")+" : " + (String) row.get("serviceName") + "<BR/>" );
}
```

Any suggestions for speeding this up? Thanks

Comment: how many rows you got in the `result`?

Comment: I am getting less than 100 rows and it takes about 4 seconds to loop through the map.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need access to entities or is it sufficient to work with nodes (and thus use the core API)? In the latter case, you could use the traversal API which is faster than Cypher.

I'm not sure what your use case is, but depending on the scenario, you could probably do something like this:

```
   for (final Path position : Traversal.description().depthFirst()
       .relationships(YOUR_RELATION_TYPE, Direction.INCOMING)
       .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_RECENT)
       .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(1)
       .traverse(facilityNode,serviceNode)) {
        // do something like e.g. position.endNode().getProperty("name")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is there a way using the traversal API to pass in a set of nodes you want to limit the traversal to? In our example above, we are passing into the Cypher query a list of node ids that we obtained from a Neo4j-spatial query that runs as the first step. We only want to include this set of nodes in the subsequent traversal.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only provide the nodes you want to start from. If here's a minimum and maximum distance between nodes, you can specify them in an Evaluator as in the example above. Next you can check if the *position.endNode()* corresponds to any node you wish.